# Locking information in rows together

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I have a Google sheet with contact information that is accessed by many people. These people need to have the ability to sort information and edit it.

Some users, when sorting, accidentally only sort information in one column, instead of sorting the entire sheet by that column. This results in mismatched contact information.

How can I make it so that users are still able to sort, but when they do, they only have the option of sorting the entire sheet?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? (if not due to sensitive intel, pls create dummy sheet with fake data and link it here)

Answer (score 1):

Add the users as viewers, not as editors, this way they will be able to use filter views to filter and sort the data but the filtering/sorting the do will not bother other users and will not change your spreadsheet.

Reference

- [Sort and filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)